# Low memory warning after Rot13 implementation

Tags: ios, objective-c, rot13

Recently i have added a rot13 function to my project so i can rot13 a string i want.The sample code was found over the internet. Right after i roted a string i am getting a low memory warning and 100% sure that this was due to the rot function.No low memory warnings prior to rot13. 
Here is my code:
**rot13.h**

```
#import <Foundation/NSString.h>

@interface NSString (rot13)
+ (NSString *)rot13:(NSString *)theText;
@end
```

**rot13.m**

```
#import "rot13.h"
@implementation NSString (rot13)

+ (NSString *)rot13:(NSString *)theText {
    NSMutableString *holder = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    unichar theChar;
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < [theText length]; i++) {
        theChar = [theText characterAtIndex:i];
        if(theChar <= 122 && theChar >= 97) {
            if(theChar + 13 > 122)
                theChar -= 13;
            else
                theChar += 13;
            [holder appendFormat:@"%hhd", (char)theChar];


        } else if(theChar <= 90 && theChar >= 65) {
            if((int)theChar + 13 > 90)
                theChar -= 13;
            else
                theChar += 13;

            [holder appendFormat:@"%C", theChar];

        } else {
            [holder appendFormat:@"%C", theChar];
        }
    }

    return [NSString stringWithString:holder];
}

@end
```

And i rot13 my string like this:

```
NSString *mystring=[defaults stringForKey:@"name"];
NSString *rotted = [NSString rot13:mystring];
```

Any help? Should i release something?Why this simple task call low memory warnings?

Comment: Is this code being compiled with ARC or MRC?

Comment: It is compile with ARC.

Comment: Then there is nothing to release.

Answer (score 3):

For every character in the string, you are running through both the string formatting processor (slow) and appending a single character to the mutable string (also slow).   Likely, one of these operations is creating an autoreleased string of some kind as an implementation detail.   Combined with the character-by-character operation, that could easily lead to memory pressure.

An off the cuff better solution would be to make a mutable copy of the input string and then iterate over the characters, replacing each as you go.   Note that ROT13 will fail miserably in the face of non 7-bit ASCII;  unicode will make it blow up.   If I remember correctly, `unichar`is a 16 bit type.

Answer (score 1):

All that string appending is most likely creating a bunch of temporary strings which aren't released until the method is finished.

You could create an `NSMutableArray` and append each character to it instead, then use `componentsJoinedByString:` to turn the array into a string in one step at the very end.

Should work...

Comment: ok i will try it out.Thanks for the responses and the help.